# What is an alternative to nesting remote forms in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, remote-forms

I have a User that can have multiple images. I would like to allow the user to add images while updating their user page and have those images dynamically updated so that they can see the images on their profile as they edit it. I currently have the images set as sortable using jQuery-ui. I would like the user to be able to add images, sort them, and edit their profile info and only need to click the submit button once.

I know that it is not possible to nest remote=>true forms and do not ***believe*** it's possible to submit files via ajax. Is there some other way this can upload the files and then use jquery to append them back to my div?

Unfortunately, from a user experience standpoint, the image section makes the most since being pretty much in the middle of the form. Moving it to the top or below the original form is less than ideal. I might be able to use CSS to make the remote form appear as if it is middle of the parent form, but this seems like a pretty bad solution.